# Python GEKKO ODE unexpected results

Tags: python, ode, gekko

I've been trying to implement an ODE model for simulation of the insulin signaling pathway, as it is presented in the [supplementary material](https://www.jbc.org/article/S0021-9258(19)48589-X/fulltext#supplementaryMaterial) of [this paper](https://www.jbc.org/article/S0021-9258(19)48589-X/fulltext#seccestitle10), using [python's GEKKO](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

The model variation implemented was the ‘Md3’, with the following equations, constant and initial values:

[image: equations]

Even though the paper does not provide the supplementary code’s outcome, one would expect the results to be curves, instead of the ones that result from my code:[image]

I have checked the equations and constant values, tried adding lower and upper bounds to the variables and experimented with the `m.options.IMODE` and `m.options.NODES` parameters, but these didn't seem to help.

Any piece of advice would be much appreciated.

```
def insulin_pathway_CM(time_interval, insulin=0): 

    m = GEKKO()
    t = np.linspace(0, time_interval-1, time_interval)
    m.time = np.insert(t,1,[1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,0.1])

    # initialization of variables
    ins = m.Param(value=insulin)
    IR = m.Var(10)
    IRp = m.Var()
    IRS = m.Var(10)
    IRSp = m.Var()
    PKB = m.Var(10)
    PKBp = m.Var()
    GLUT4_C = m.Var(10)
    GLUT4_M = m.Var()
  
    # initialization of constants                                                                                                                                                 
    k1aBasic = 1863.78                                                                   
    k1f = 38668.300000000003                                                             
    k1b = 40229000                                                                       
    k2f = 401394                                                                         
    k2b = 36704300                                                                       
    k4f = 336782                                                                         
    k4b = 187399  
    k5Basic = 85530.899999999994  
    k5f = 11264.799999999999 
    k5b = 26389900   

    # equations
    m.Equation(IR.dt() == k1b*IRp - (k1f*ins*1000*IR + k1aBasic*IR))
    m.Equation(IRp.dt() == -k1b*IRp + k1f*ins*1000*IR + k1aBasic*IR)
    m.Equation(IRS.dt() == k2b*IRSp - (k2f*IRp*IRS))
    m.Equation(IRSp.dt() == -k2b*IRSp + k2f*IRp*IRS)
    m.Equation(PKB.dt() == k4b*PKBp - k4f*IRSp*PKB)
    m.Equation(PKBp.dt() == -k4b*PKBp + k4f*IRSp*PKB)
    m.Equation(GLUT4_C.dt() == k5b*GLUT4_M - (k5f*PKBp*GLUT4_C + k5Basic*GLUT4_C))
    m.Equation(GLUT4_M.dt() == -k5b*GLUT4_M + (k5f*PKBp*GLUT4_C + k5Basic*GLUT4_C))

    m.options.IMODE = 7
    m.options.OTOL  = 1e-8
    m.options.RTOL  = 1e-8
    m.options.NODES = 3
    m.solve(disp=False)

    # plotting
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 2, figsize=(20, 20))
    axs[0, 0].plot(m.time, IR)
    axs[0, 0].set_title('IR(t)')
    axs[0, 1].plot(m.time, IRp)
    axs[0, 1].set_title('IRp(t)')
    axs[1, 0].plot(m.time, IRS, 'tab:orange')
    axs[1, 0].set_title('IRS(t)')
    axs[1, 1].plot(m.time, IRSp, 'tab:green')
    axs[1, 1].set_title('IRSp(t)')
    axs[2, 0].plot(m.time, PKB, 'tab:red')
    axs[2, 0].set_title('PKB(t)')
    axs[2, 1].plot(m.time, PKBp, 'tab:purple')
    axs[2, 1].set_title('PKBp(t)')
    axs[3, 0].plot(m.time, GLUT4_C, 'tab:olive')
    axs[3, 0].set_title('GLUT4_C(t)')
    axs[3, 1].plot(m.time, GLUT4_M, 'tab:cyan')
    axs[3, 1].set_title('GLUT4_M(t)')
    
    plt.figure()
    plt.show()
    return

time_interval = 60
insulin = 100
insulin_pathway_CM(time_interval, insulin)
```

Comment: You have a system with coefficients like `k1f*ins*1000=38668.3*1e+05=3.86683e+09` in a linear term. This means that the time scale where interesting things happen is measured in multiples of `1e-9`. Reduce the integration time span accordingly. (and round away the floating point errors, these 0er and 9er segments are meaningless)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lutz Lehmann is correct. A plot of the derivatives with an ending time of 1e-5 shows that most of the action happens in a short period of time.

[image: derivatives]

Try a shorter time span.

```py
m.time = np.linspace(0,1e-5,100)
```

This shows the fast dynamics.

[image: fast dynamics]

There is likely an error with the equations such as a units issue (time in days or years?) or the authors forgot to include some type of `volume` factor for the patient such as blood volume or body volume.

```py
# equations
V1 = 1e9  # hypothetical volume 1
V2 = 10   # hypothetical volume 2
m.Equation(V1*IR.dt() == k1b*IRp - (k1f*ins*1000*IR + k1aBasic*IR))
m.Equation(V1*IRp.dt() == -k1b*IRp + k1f*ins*1000*IR + k1aBasic*IR)
m.Equation(V1*IRS.dt() == k2b*IRSp - (k2f*IRp*IRS))
m.Equation(V1*IRSp.dt() == -k2b*IRSp + k2f*IRp*IRS)
m.Equation(V2*PKB.dt() == k4b*PKBp - k4f*IRSp*PKB)
m.Equation(V2*PKBp.dt() == -k4b*PKBp + k4f*IRSp*PKB)
m.Equation(V2*GLUT4_C.dt() == k5b*GLUT4_M - (k5f*PKBp*GLUT4_C + k5Basic*GLUT4_C))
m.Equation(V2*GLUT4_M.dt() == -k5b*GLUT4_M + (k5f*PKBp*GLUT4_C + k5Basic*GLUT4_C))
```

Here are more reasonable dynamics with the original time scale (0-60 hrs).

[image: Original time scale]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def insulin_pathway_CM(time_interval, insulin=0): 

    m = GEKKO()
    t = np.linspace(0, time_interval-1, time_interval)
    m.time = np.insert(t,1,[1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,0.1])

    # initialization of variables
    ins = m.Param(value=insulin)
    IR = m.Var(10)
    IRp = m.Var()
    IRS = m.Var(10)
    IRSp = m.Var()
    PKB = m.Var(10)
    PKBp = m.Var()
    GLUT4_C = m.Var(10)
    GLUT4_M = m.Var()
  
    # initialization of constants
    k1aBasic = 1863.78      
    k1f = 38668.300000000003  
    k1b = 40229000  
    k2f = 401394 
    k2b = 36704300 
    k4f = 336782
    k4b = 187399  
    k5Basic = 85530.899999999994  
    k5f = 11264.799999999999 
    k5b = 26389900   

    # calculate derivatives
    d = m.Array(m.Var,8)
    m.Equation(d[0] == k1b*IRp - (k1f*ins*1000*IR + k1aBasic*IR))
    m.Equation(d[1] == -k1b*IRp + k1f*ins*1000*IR + k1aBasic*IR)
    m.Equation(d[2] == k2b*IRSp - (k2f*IRp*IRS))
    m.Equation(d[3] == -k2b*IRSp + k2f*IRp*IRS)
    m.Equation(d[4] == k4b*PKBp - k4f*IRSp*PKB)
    m.Equation(d[5] == -k4b*PKBp + k4f*IRSp*PKB)
    m.Equation(d[6] == k5b*GLUT4_M - (k5f*PKBp*GLUT4_C + k5Basic*GLUT4_C))
    m.Equation(d[7] == -k5b*GLUT4_M + (k5f*PKBp*GLUT4_C + k5Basic*GLUT4_C))    

    # equations
    V1 = 1e9  # hypothetical volume 1
    V2 = 10   # hypothetical volume 2
    m.Equation(V1*IR.dt() == k1b*IRp - (k1f*ins*1000*IR + k1aBasic*IR))
    m.Equation(V1*IRp.dt() == -k1b*IRp + k1f*ins*1000*IR + k1aBasic*IR)
    m.Equation(V1*IRS.dt() == k2b*IRSp - (k2f*IRp*IRS))
    m.Equation(V1*IRSp.dt() == -k2b*IRSp + k2f*IRp*IRS)
    m.Equation(V2*PKB.dt() == k4b*PKBp - k4f*IRSp*PKB)
    m.Equation(V2*PKBp.dt() == -k4b*PKBp + k4f*IRSp*PKB)
    m.Equation(V2*GLUT4_C.dt() == k5b*GLUT4_M - (k5f*PKBp*GLUT4_C + k5Basic*GLUT4_C))
    m.Equation(V2*GLUT4_M.dt() == -k5b*GLUT4_M + (k5f*PKBp*GLUT4_C + k5Basic*GLUT4_C))

    m.options.IMODE = 4
    m.options.OTOL  = 1e-8
    m.options.RTOL  = 1e-8
    m.options.NODES = 3
    m.solve(disp=True)

    # plotting
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(4, 2, figsize=(20, 20))
    axs[0, 0].plot(m.time, IR)
    axs[0, 0].set_title('IR(t)')
    axs[0, 1].plot(m.time, IRp)
    axs[0, 1].set_title('IRp(t)')
    axs[1, 0].plot(m.time, IRS, 'tab:orange')
    axs[1, 0].set_title('IRS(t)')
    axs[1, 1].plot(m.time, IRSp, 'tab:green')
    axs[1, 1].set_title('IRSp(t)')
    axs[2, 0].plot(m.time, PKB, 'tab:red')
    axs[2, 0].set_title('PKB(t)')
    axs[2, 1].plot(m.time, PKBp, 'tab:purple')
    axs[2, 1].set_title('PKBp(t)')
    axs[3, 0].plot(m.time, GLUT4_C, 'tab:olive')
    axs[3, 0].set_title('GLUT4_C(t)')
    axs[3, 1].plot(m.time, GLUT4_M, 'tab:cyan')
    axs[3, 1].set_title('GLUT4_M(t)')

    plt.figure()
    for i in range(8):
        plt.plot(m.time,d[i].value)
    
    plt.show()
    return

time_interval = 60
insulin = 100
insulin_pathway_CM(time_interval, insulin)
```

For reference, here is a [simplified blood glucose response model](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/DiabeticBloodGlucose) (similar to Bergman model) for your reference. Richard Bergman and Claudio Cobelli proposed a minimal model in 1979 to describe blood glucose and insulin dynamics.